# Error while set image src in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to set image src in JavaScript file whit this code :

```
p3GalleryBp.src = "/Uploded/foo.jpg";
```

when run my page, image src is empty and when inspect the image see a message in the end of image tag :

> ==$0

[image: scrin shot of error]

but when i use jquery it work fine, anybody know how i solve this problem?

Comment: [The `== $0` indicates you can access the element in the console using the variable `$0`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#0-4). It is set as a convenience and is not related to your issue of setting an image's `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is variable "p3GalleryBp" defined in some way before, or you're trying to address element directly by it's ID? Seems like there should be something like:

```
document.getElementById("p3GalleryBp").src = "/Uploded/foo.jpg";
```

Comment: Elements with an `id` attribute are available on `window` via their ID already. :-)

Comment: @sdgluck yesss...its my typo mistake ...i define it befor :)

Comment: @sdgluck in your opinion witch code have better speed and performance:  $("#p3GalleryBp").attr("src",'foo.jpg') or   p3GalleryBp.src = "/Uploded/foo.jpg";

Comment: @sdgluck not always and not everywhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables ...

Comment: @MaksimVolkov Thanks. :-) My comment was more a pointer to this not being the issue, rather than a suggestion that this behaviour be used.